# Trigger query click event inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, click

I have an add button that creates a row of fields and based on the user input I'd like to perform the click() event and have the rows created automatically.

I have a for loop to take care of this, where the click event should be fired based on the number of rows the user intends to have.

Here is the code,

```
//this will add the required number of rows
function createDoorSelections(doors){
    for (var index = 0; index < doors; index++) {
        //console.log("Creating door: "+ index);
        jQuery('.frm_add_form_row').click();
    }
}
```

For some reason, only one row gets created irrelevant to the input from the user. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: You haven't posted enough code to provide an answer; so far all you've shown is a for loop that triggers a click event on all elements matching the `.from_add_form_row` selector. Please: read the "*[mcve]*" guidance in order that we can help you more usefully and help those who follow in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhhh, I am assuming that the type of `doors` is an `Array` right? If so, inside of your for loop, it should be the following

```
index < doors.length;
```

**Update**: I have tested the following code. You need to use `.trigger('click')` for your desired output.

Trigger executes the click event that you attached to elements with class `.frm_add_form_row`. For more information on `.trigger()`, read the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

The code below, on startup, will execute the click event attached to elements with class `.frm_add_form_row` six times.

For your convenience, here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z7tnbuh/3/) for you to test it out.

```
<html>
<body>
    <button class="frm_add_form_row">Click me</button>
</body>
<!-- Add your own jquery script import -->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.frm_add_form_row').click(function() {
            alert("clicked");
        });
        // Execute alert("clicked"); 6 times on load.
        createDoorSelections(6);
    });
    //this will add the required number of rows
    function createDoorSelections(doors){
        for (var index = 0; index < doors; index++) {
            //console.log("Creating door: "+ index);
            jQuery('.frm_add_form_row').trigger('click');
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: it's an integer. the loop itself works fine. Verified it with console output.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info. Let me create a fiddle quickly and get back to you.

Comment: I have attached my updated answer above. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution pls

```
//this will add the required number of rows
function createDoorSelections(doors){
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var index = 0; index < doors; index++) {
        //console.log("Creating door: "+ index);
        jQuery('.frm_add_form_row').click();
      }
    });
}
```